# Can't run "mvn install" successfully on Java EE 7 tutorials

Tags: jakarta-ee, derby, javadb, glassfish-4

According to the Java EE 7 tutorial, I reached the point where I need to install the samples archetypes by running the command "mvn install".

I'm prompted this error

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] PER01003: Deployment encountered SQL Exceptions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Command deploy failed.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE SETUPOFFICE (EMPLOYEEID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, EMPLOYEENAME VARCHAR(255), EQU
IPMENTLIST VARCHAR(255), OFFICENUMBER INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEEID))": java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'SETUPOFFICE' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
```

My questions are:

- Where is is SQL query located ?!
- How can I login to the JavaDB schema to fix this ? I downlaoded SQuirreL SQL client but I do not know what are the credentials\schema name I should use

More importantly, please mention the source of your information. This tutorial is very hard to follow and I intend to finish it, so I need to my way around.

Answer (score 0):

JavaDB (Derby) connection information is:

```
Address: localhost
Username: APP
Password: APP
Schema name: sun-appserv-samples
```

I got this from the JDBC connection pools from the pool named "DerbyPool"